# Sharing a Realm Database between a user's devices

Tags: ios, database, realm

Is there a formal way for a Realm Database to be shared between a users iPhone and iPad? Clearly that will need some kind of server that a database can be pushed and pulled from. Is there a solution for this, like is there a way to use iCloud?

If not does anyone one have any ideas for a path of least resistance for implementing this myself?

Found this chat on the Realm's GitHub page 
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/913
I am still hoping someone here has got around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm hasn't provided sync feature yet. We are actively working on sync building feature, but we don't have no ETA at the moment.

Easy ways are sharing Realm data file with iCloud or other services. e.g. DropBox API.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Or this library might help you...? https://github.com/BellAppLab/RealmCloudKit

Second, using serverside database to sync with local database. Like Parse.com.

https://parse.com/