# How Can I Setup My iOS App To Use Automatic iCloud Backup?

Tags: swift, ios8, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have written an app the uses the RealmDB, which produces a file called default.realm. This is the database storage file. I would like to setup my app to make use of the iCloud automatic backup feature. How can I setup my app to do this?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876751/sharing-a-realm-database-between-a-users-devices/33886354#33886354

Answer (score 4):

You can't! Because your app is already set up like that! :)

According to the [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) page on Apple's website, all files in an app's `Documents` folder will automatically be backed up to iCloud, or the user's local iTunes account if they've chosen such. This is *on by default*, and must be [explicitly disabled through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056556/disable-backup-of-documents-folder-and-all-its-sub-folders-on-icloud) if disabling backup is desired.

By default, Realm places `default.realm` in the Documents directory for this exact reason: to ensure any user-generated data stored in it will be properly backed up in through iCloud and/or iTunes sync operations.

So you don't need to worry! Your Realm data is already being properly backed up by iCloud as we speak! :)

Comment: I have heard from multiple users and personally experienced that my own app seems to not be captured by this iCloud backup so it seems some exceptions to the "automatic" assumption may be worth asking about. Is anyone aware of when/why an app might not be backed up while others are?